# What range of relative humidity is present in the combustion byproducts of a natural gas stove, immediately after combustion?

Tags: combustion, humidity

If I have a traditional gas range-top, burning natural gas (instead of LPG or propane), what is the typical range of humidity present in the combustion byproducts immediately above the flame? The combustion process adds water to the air, and the natural gas has an inherent humidity as well. However, the combustion process also dramatically raises the temperature, thus significantly drying the air.

Comment: Why would there be any *relative* humidity immediately after combustion? Temperature is higher then boiling point of water.

Comment: @Mithoron No problem as long as there still exists a saturation pressure at that temperature. For example, pure steam at 120 °C and 1 bar has a relative humidity of about 50 %. Whether this is useful information, is a different question.

Comment: Whoa, generally in SE we don't downvote without leaving explanations, esp. for new contributors. If the question is dumb, please explain why. FWIW, it looks like there is an answer, which is that it is undefined.

Comment: Well, you just shouldn't ask about relative, but absolute or specific humidity. Relative one is highly dependent on temperature, even if it was below critical temperature. We don't really know what you want to find out here, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Mithoron thanks for the clarification. I'm curious if the combustion process makes the air generally wetter or generally drier. I've taken classes in thermodynamics related to powerplants, so I've never worked with temperatures so high (or low) that we've discussed critical points as something other than curiosities.

Comment: Well, then I guess it's mostly about your misconception in the last sentence. I don't get why you'd think heating dries air.

Comment: @Mithoron relative humidity changes with temperature. I guess it comes down to whether we consider air is dry because of RH or molar mass. I'm happy to learn my usage of the word "dry" is wrong, and subsequently reword my question.

Comment: So again this relative humidity... the air isn't getting any drier, it's just that the saturation vapor pressure increases. That's again a reason not to use RH here.

Comment: Burning 0.1 m3 of NG provides (after mixing with air and cooling) formally 0.2 m3 of pure vapor. If the room has 50 m3, it is 0.004 m3/m3. Saturated vapor pressure at 25 deg C is 3130 Pa, what is approximately 0.03 m3 vapor/ 1 m3 air. 0.004/0.03 .100 = approx 13% of the room relative humidity increase. For lower T it would be more. Note also that relative humidity falls to by rule of thumb to 1/2 by air warming up by 10 deg C. So the actual change if relative humidity would very much depend on the rate of burning and of room cooling down.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming ideal conditions starting from dry air, the theoretical mixture immediately after complete combustion contains $19\ \%$ $\ce{H2O}$ (molar fraction) since the oxygen from the air is replaced according to

$$\ce{CH4 + 2 O2 -> CO2 + 2 H2O}$$

However, the adiabatic flame temperature in air (not oxygen) is $2236\ \mathrm K$, which is well above the critical point temperature of $647\ \mathrm K$. Therefore, the relative humidity (i.e. the  ratio of the partial pressure of water vapor to the saturation vapor pressure) is not defined at such temperatures immediately after combustion.

Comment: "relative humidity  is not defined at such temperatures immediately after combustion." Thanks for this, I had no idea. I'm going to have to read about that to get a better sense of what it even means.